# How do I Query For Defects where with a requirement under a particular feature

Tags: rally, appsdk2

When using a custom grid query based on defects I often filter based on the tags of the linked user story. I would like to use the actual feature hierarchy. e.g. Show all defects where the linked story is under a given feature or initiative.  I could not work this out from looking at the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags attribute exists on Artifact object from which Requirement inherits, hence Requirement.Tags can be traversed. Feature attribute does not exist on Requirement. It exists on HierarchicalRequirement, which inherits from Requirement, hence Requirement.Feature cannot be traversed.
In this context a custom grid may not be a suitable choice. But a custom app can be written that shows all those relationships. Here is a custom app that has two comboboxes: a Release and a Feature. The Feature combobox is populated based on the selection in the Release combobox. When a feature is selected from the second combobox a grid is populated with the feature's child stories and defects (if any) associated with those stories.
You may see the full code [in this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/feature-picker), and copy the [html file](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/feature-picker/blob/master/deploy/App.html) into a custom page.

Here is the js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'release',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a Release:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },
    addContent: function() {
        this._makeCombobox();
    },

   onScopeChange: function() {
        this._makeCombobox();
    },

    _makeCombobox: function() {
    if (this.down('#features')) {
        this.down('#features').destroy();
    }
    var features = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
        id: 'features',
        storeConfig: {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','Release', 'UserStories'],
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()]
        },
        fieldLabel: 'select Feature',
        listeners:{
                ready: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            console.log('ready',combobox.getRecord().get('_ref'));
            this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
            else{
            console.log('selected release has no features');
            if (this.down('#grid')) {
                this.down('#grid').destroy();
            }
            }
        },
                select: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            console.log('select',combobox.getRecord().get('_ref'));
            this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }

                },
                scope: this
            }
    });
    this.add(features);
    },
    _onFeatureSelected:function(feature){
    console.log('feature', feature.get('Name'));

     var f  = {
            FormattedID: feature.get('FormattedID'),
            Name: feature.get('Name'),
            _ref: feature.get("_ref"),
            UserStories: []
        };

    var collection = feature.getCollection('UserStories', {fetch: ['Name','FormattedID','Owner', 'Defects']});
    var that = this;
    var count = collection.getCount();
    console.log(count);
    var stories = [];
    var pendingStories = count;
      collection.load({
            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                Ext.Array.each(records, function(story){
             var s  = {
                                FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: story.get('Name'),
                                _ref: story.get("_ref"),
                                DefectCount: story.get('Defects').Count,
                                Defects: []
                            };
                var defects = story.getCollection('Defects');
                var defectcount = defects.getCount();
                var pendingDefects = defectcount;
                 defects.load({
                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(defect){
                                        s.Defects.push({_ref: defect.get('_ref'),
                                                        FormattedID: defect.get('FormattedID')
                                                    });
                                    }, this);

                                    --pendingDefects;
                                    if (pendingDefects === 0) {
                     console.log(story.get('FormattedID') + ' - ' + story.get('Name'));
                    --pendingStories;
                     if (pendingStories === 0) {
                        console.log('stories inside callback',stories);
                     }

                                    }
                    console.log('makeGrid');
                                    that._makeGrid(stories);
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
            stories.push(s);
            }, this);           
        }

        });
    },

     _makeGrid: function(stories) {
     var c = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
        },
        x: 400
    });
    this.add(c);
        this._store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: stories,
                pageSize: 100,
                remoteSort:false
            });

        if (!this.down('#grid')){
         c.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            itemId: 'grid',
            store: this._store,
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
                },
         {
                    text: 'Defect Count', dataIndex: 'DefectCount'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Defects', dataIndex: 'Defects', 
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        var html = [];
                        Ext.Array.each(value, function(defect){
                            html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(defect) + '">' + defect.FormattedID + '</a>')
                        });
                        return html.join(', ');
                    }
                }
            ]

        });
        }
        else{
            this.down('#grid').reconfigure(this._store);
        }
    }
});
```

[image]